# Laravel Appends

Tags: laravel, append

I have 2 tables.
1.users , 2. user_meta

```
----------------------      ----------------------
|       users          |         user_meta
----------------------     ----------------------
|id | name | password  |   id|user_id|meta_key|meta_value
 5   xxx      xxxx          1  5       height  6
```

I want output like:
`{'id':1,'name':'xxx','height':6}`

what i did at User Model**(simply append height to the User Model)**

```
Protected $appends = ['height'];

public function getHeightAttribute($height)
{
    $height= (new UserMeta)->getUserMeta('height',$this->id);
    return $height;
}
```

But if i have many meta values like: height,age,sex,color,etc... then i don't think it's a good idea to append all meta data to user Model. 
Is there any Better solution to get response like `{'id':1,'name':'xxx','height':6,'age':24,continue...}`  without appending to user Model ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty straightforward, this is your User model will be like.

1. Define your meta relationship name in this case i will use `metadata`
2. Eager load your metadata relationship on every user query
3. Hide your relationship value on json/array form of the model
4. set get attribute mutator, IMPORTANT: must be different name with relationship name
5. append your attributes on `meta` attributes.

   ```
   class User {
       // 2. eager load user metadata on every user query
       protected $with = [ 'metadata' ];

       // 3. hide the relationship data from array/json
       protected $hidden = [ 'metadata' ];

       // 5. append meta attribute mutator
       protected $append = [ 'meta' ];

       // 1. your user meta relationship
       public function metadata() {
           return $this->hasMany(UserMeta::model, 'user_id', 'id');
       }

       // 4. `meta` get attribute mutator
       public function getMetaAttribute() {
           return $this->metadata->mapWithKeys(function($meta) {
               return [$meta['meta_key'] => $meta['meta_value']]
           })->all();
       }
   }
   ```

This will result in:

```
$user->toJson();

// result
{
  ...
  'email': 'email@domain.com',
  'meta': {
      'key1': 'value1',
      'key2': 'value2'
   }
   ...
}
```

This, in my opinion is better reflection for your code, instead of merging directly with original user attributes, since you can set `setMetaAttribute` to update your metadata relationship.

but if you insist to merge everything with user attributes, you have to override 2 methods, `__get($attribute)` and/or `toArray()` method on your user models.